# nth-child не работает

Tags: css

Вот код

```
.top-side li:nth-child(2) a{
    background-position: 15px -40px;
  }
.top-side li:nth-child(3) a{
    background-position: 15px -82px;
  }
.top-side li:nth-child(4) a{
    background-position: 15px -122px;
  }
```

Конкретный пример

```css
.top-side {
  height: 145px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c6d8ee, #e7eff7);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c6d8ee, #e7eff7);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c6d8ee, #e7eff7);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c6d8ee, #e7eff7);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #c6d8ee, #e7eff7);
}
.top-side li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 145px;
  float: left;
  font-family: "CleanvertisingLight";
}
.top-side ul {
  height: 145px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.top-side ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 75px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-image: url(../img/icon-set-side.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px -10px;
}
.top-side ul li span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.top-side ul li strong {
  font-size: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.top-side li:nth-child(2) a {
  background-position: 15px -40px;
}
.top-side li:nth-child(3) a {
  background-position: 15px -82px;
}
.top-side li:nth-child(4) a {
  background-position: 15px -122px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-side">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <ul>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <li><a href="#">Более 10 лет<br /><span>На рынке</span></a>
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <li><a href="#">Самые Современные<br /><span>Методики</span></a>
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <li><a href="#">Квалифицированные<br /><span>Преподаватели</span></a>
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <li><a href="#">Гарантированное получение<br /><span>Высоких знаний</span></a>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uq33t5ke/

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

`nth-child` [работает](https://jsbin.com/havoza/2/edit?html,css,output) . Проверьте, не перезаписано ли свойство (`!important`). Проверьте в отладчике структуру html. Если не поможет - создайте [jsbin](http://jsbin.com)

UPDATE:

По сслыке на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uq33t5ke/) становится всё понятно: вы не учитываете, что nth-child считается от пэрента, а он у ваших li всегда div, таким образом ваш `li` - **всегда первый** чайлд. Делайте `.top-site ul > div:nth-child`

PS: Лучше не вкладывать их в div, а использовать структуру вида:

```
<ul>
  <li class="col-md-3"></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Comment: поправил ответ.

Comment: всё ли верно в этом решении?

Answer (score 1):

Да, не работает. Потому что в разметке фигня.

```
<ul>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <li><a href="#">Более 10 лет<br /><span>На рынке</span></a>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <li><a href="#">Самые Современные<br /><span>Методики</span></a>
    </li>
  </div>
```

Что тут делаю div'ы? Браузер это прожевал, но вот любой `li` является первым потомком родительского `div`а, а не вторым, третьим и четвёртым. Так что мимо.